# cmake -D <var>:<type>=<value>: what can <type> be?

Tags: cmake

`-D <var>:<type>=<value>`: Create a cmake cache entry.

ok, but what can `<type>` be? I've seen BOOL, STRING, PATH, FILEPATH. What else can that type be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the CMake man page, under "Properties on Cache Entries":

```
TYPE   Widget type for entry in GUIs.

    Cache entry values are always strings, but CMake GUIs present widgets to help users set values.  The GUIs use this property as a hint to determine the widget type.  Valid TYPE values are:

            BOOL          = Boolean ON/OFF value.
            PATH          = Path to a directory.
            FILEPATH      = Path to a file.
            STRING        = Generic string value.
            INTERNAL      = Do not present in GUI at all.
            STATIC        = Value managed by CMake, do not change.
            UNINITIALIZED = Type not yet specified.

          Generally the TYPE of a cache entry should be set by the command which creates it (set, option, find_library, etc.).
```